# Which library should I use to connect to a socket.io 1.0 server in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

We just updated our servers to socket.io 1.0, but it breaks backward compatibility with older client libraries. Previously, I used https://github.com/lukabernardi/AZSocketIO but it does not support socket.io 1.0, so I need to switch to something else.

The official client is Swift only, but adding Swift would make my app way bigger and the blog post is not too enticing ("It can be used with Objective-C projects, but will require some extra work")

I took a look at this: https://github.com/MegaBits/SIOSocket but it uses a WebView as the implementation, which I tend to find ... awkward.

Is there any better solution out there that I did not find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the square socket client:

https://github.com/square/SocketRocket

I have used it and found it very easy to get up and running.